# Как осуществить переход на следующий элемент пагинации, если не меняется ссылка при переходе?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Пишу парсер для вот этого сайта: https://eldorado.ua/search/?q=Gazer

И на этом сайте при переходе на следующую страницу не меняется url, и программе не удается найти элемент "Следующая страница", как быть?

Вот код парсера:

https://dpaste.org/4FXW

```
try:
        while True:
            print('Load:', url)
            driver.get(url)

            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".goods-item-content"):

                try:name = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.tile-container').text

                except NoSuchElementException:name = ''

                # Не у всех товаров есть цена
                try:
                    price = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.current-price').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    price = '-'

                try:nal = item_el.find_element_by_css_selector('.buy-button-placeholder').text
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    nal = " "

                row = name, price, nal
                print(row)
                items.append(row)

            # Если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, то продолжаем цикл, иначе завершаем
            try:
                a_next_page = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.page-i:last-child')
                url = a_next_page.get_attribute('href')

            except NoSuchElementException:
                break

    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

Вот код элемента пагинации:

```css
pages .page-i:last-child {
    border: none;
}
.pages .page-i {
    width: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 4px;
}
ul:not(.browser-default) li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.pages>div, .pages li {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #484b4c;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<li class="page-i"><div class="back_pagin" id="goods_back"><img class="to-left" src="/img/icons/icon-pagination-left.svg" alt="icon-pagination-left"></div></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измени логику. Открываем url в браузере, далее если есть кнопка перехода на следующую страницу, продолжаем цикл пока кнопка не изчезнеть в итоге мы имеем полностью загруженный код страницы в браузере. Гуляем по нужным css_selector-ам.